# RIP Rene Auberjonois - Star Trek DS9 Actor and Director

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Rene Auberjonois has died at the age of 79. He is best known for his role as Constable Odo in Deep Space Nine as well as directing a number of Star Trek episodes including the critically acclaimed [*DS9: Hippocratic Oath*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hippocratic_Oath_(episode)).

Comment: He's gone back to the Great Link. Odo is my favourite Star Trek character. Mr Auberjonois did such a great job with him, especially under all that make-up.

Comment: to me, as much as I love DS9, simply because this is where I saw him first - he'll always be Clayton Endicott, III from 'Benson' - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-iCSiG96wg

Comment: Looking him up on IMDB, I was surprised at just how many prolific his career had been.  I'd also completely forgotten he was Father Mulcahy in the movie MASH.

Comment: Bad week for Star Trek, first DC Fontana, now Auberjonois. I discovered him in DS9, loved his portrayal of Odo and how the character evolved throughout the show. RIP.

Comment: He was also known for his voice acting and in particular the character of Mr. House in Fallout: New Vegas, an amazing game even after all those years mainly due to the voice acting talent and all the Trek alumni (Rene Auberjonois, Michael Dorn, Adam Sadler).

Comment: I've seen Mr. Auberjonois in many roles over the years. His more recent portrayal of the [tag:Warehouse 13] systems creator sticks with me. I don't personally know of any predilection to add Sci-Fi roles to his filmography but there did see to be a bias in that direction.

Comment: Goodbye Constable.

Comment: @Rebel-Scum he also voiced [Janos Audron](https://legacyofkain.fandom.com/wiki/Janos_Audron) in the *Legacy of Kain* series. It's my most memorable exposure to Mr Auberjonois. May he rest in peace.

Comment: The upvotes seem to send a mixed message. RIP.

Comment: @HamSandwich - Upvotes just mean "I agree with this post"

Comment: Yeah, I get it. But if it means "I like this," you can see what I mean, I trust. That said, Valorum, do you like the character Odo?

Comment: I liked (and first saw) him in Boston Legal, too. I thought, gee, this guy should have more acting roles. He did!

Answer (score 6):

I'll always remember him as Clayton Endicott III.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIELFX6CFyo

Answer (score 3):

His role as Odo in DS9 is the main role that he played that I'll remember him for. Other than that his role as Hugo Miller in Warehouse 13 and his role as Alar in Stargate Sg-1.

R.I.P. Rene :(

Answer (score 2):

My first ever exposure to this brilliant actor was not as Odo, the grouchy, yet fair and shrewed Head of Security on DS9.... but as an incredible voice from my childhood. He played *many* voice roles in favored cartoons, including the voice of a Dassad, Darkseid's main aid in the **Super Powers Team: Galactic Guardians,** several voices in **The GoBots**, several characters in various Marvel productions, and would *Again* lend his voice talents to DC, this time as the first animated voice of General Zod in the 1988 **Superman** cartoon series. He was even the voice of that crazed Chef in **The Little Mermaid.**

I would later find out he continued doing voices well into the 2000s, such as Talos in **God of War.** All this, and he would pop up in several non-sci-fi shows; my absolute favorite role outside of Odo was his similar, if more comedic role as Paul, a senior partner on the Dramedy **Boston Legal.**  The man was a multi-talented actor of stage, screen, television and video game, and his presence is already missed.